# Setting language on Steam web API

Tags: rest, internationalization, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get the list of my achived achivments, but I cannot get the description of the achivment. It also seems that I does not accept the language paremeter.

Based on the [official documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetUserStatsForGame_.28v0002.29) I tried to use this url:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?l=de&appid=400&key=<insert-api-key>&steamid=76561197993036744
```

I also tried the pameters `lang` and `language` with the values `de_DE`, `en` and `en_US`. Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the wrong API. You need to call:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?l=german&appid=400&key=<insert-api-key>&steamid=76561197993036744
```

Answer (score 1):

add `l=german` to the request url

Example:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=570&l=english
```